How to initialize multiple databases in different threads
this is my first post. I have a TypeOrm project where i want to connect to few databases and execute a function in each one, but i have to do it in different threads to avoid blockages. I have a data-source.ts file with the database configuration and the index.ts file with the main code (U can see below)
try {
  AppDataSource.initialize().then(async () => {
  await readFile(principalDir);
  const cncsS02 = await getCncS02();
  const cncsS04 = await getCncS04();
  const cncsS05 = await getCncS05();
  await associateDatesS04(cncsS04);
  await associateDatesS05(cncsS05);
  await associateDatesS02(cncsS02);


  setInterval(() => {
    readFile(principalDir); // Pasar el directorio como parámetro a readFile
  }, interval);
    
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))
} catch(err) {
  console.error('Error al leer los archivos: ', err);
}

I hope u can help me and sorry for my English :D
I have tried with a worker.ts with the main functionality, but i keep getting SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module and cant solve it
try {

  AppDataSource.initialize().then(async () => {

    const worker1 = new Worker('./worker.ts', { workerData: { principalDir }});

    worker1.on('error', error => {
        console.error('Error en el hilo 1:', error);
    });

  
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))


} catch(err) {
  console.error('Error al leer los archivos: ', err);
}

